# Update Database in doOnComplete or doOnCancel in spring boot 3 webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm working on a Spring boot 3 application that consumes a Flux and continually sends data to the frontend client. When the connection is either successfully completed or cancelled, I need to perform some additional actions.

Specifically, I would like to increase the number of AI requests using `aiConfigService.increaseAIRequestCount().subscribe()`. However, when attempting these actions within the `doOnComplete` and `doOnCancel` callbacks, I get a warning, `Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking context`.

Moreover, these callbacks are not in a position to access the `contextView` in the `Flux.deferContextual(contextView -> {})`, which is required for the execution of `aiConfigService.increaseAIRequestCount().subscribe()`.

```java
public Flux<AIChat> askQuestion() {
    return Flux.deferContextual(contextView -> {
        // Code handling Context view...
        return aiRepository.askQuestion()
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                //some code
            })
            .doOnCancel(() -> {
                aiConfigService.increaseAIRequestCount().subscribe();
            })
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                aiConfigService.increaseAIRequestCount().subscribe();
        });
    });
}
```

```java
public Mono<AIConfig> increaseAIRequestCount() {
    return getAIConfig().flatMap(aiConfig -> {
        //some code
        return aiConfigRepository.save(aiConfig);
    });
}
```

```java
public Flux<AIConfig> getAIConfig() {
    return Flux.deferContextual(contextView -> {
        //some code
    });
}
```

When `doOnComplete` or `doOnCancel` are invoked, I get a warning: `Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking context`. And, I'm unable to access the context in these blocks.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there another way to handle the implementation of additional actions that need to be carried out in `doOnComplete` or `doOnCancel` without getting the subscribe warning?
2. What would be the correct way to perform actions in `doOnComplete` and `doOnCancel` blocks within Project Reactor, such that I am not getting the subscribe warning while ensuring the Flux continues to send data without interruptions?
3. Is there a way to read `contextView` in the `doOnComplete` and `doOnCancel` blocks?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you for your help!